# I am trying to make an object with a velocity that will swap every 2 seconds

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is my code and I am not sure what is wrong

```css
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class vswap : MonoBehaviour {
 void Update() {
  if (1=1){
   yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
   rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0+this.transform.position.y, 0);
   Debug.Log("velocity swap");
  } 
 }
}
```

And this is the error:
    Assets/vswap.cs(4,14): error CS1624: The body of `vswap.Update()' cannot be an iterator block because`void' is not an iterator interface type

```
It used to have while instead of if but that did not fix it
I also tried to use IEnumerator instead of void but that did not work
```

Comment: You should start your question with a broader description of what your solution attempts to do.  You should also try and provide as much contextual debugging as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have put the code of a Coroutine inside your Update method. 
So that "yeild" keyword will not work.
Also, the line "if (1=1){" is always true - that's a mistake you're probably run into later.

Take a look at this [tutorial on using corroutines](http://unitypatterns.com/scripting-with-coroutines/) on UnityPatterns.com

its what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Plastic Surgeon is correct. I just thought I would help you along a bit and supply some code that should work, but also take into consideration that it is completely untested.

```
private void Start()
{
   velocity = valueOne;
   StartCoroutine(Velocity);
}
public IEnumerator Velocity()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    velocity = velocity == valueOne ? valueTwo: valueOne;
}
```

Try something along those lines, like I said I didn't test any of this, and there may be a better way to do it. But definitely look up the tutorials on coroutines if you're going to be using them, always good to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

First one, You don´t need the "if(1=1)" because it´s always true.

Now, you could do it this way (using and updating the code from Repareman):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class vswap : MonoBehaviour {
    private int velocity =2;
    private int speed1=2;
    private int speed2=4;
    private void Start()
    {
        Speed ();
    }
    public IEnumerator Speed()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        velocity = velocity == speed1 ? speed2: speed2;
        Speed();
    }
}
```

Now just change the rigibody´s velocity for the new vale and that´s all :D